# Scroll View is not disabled in CollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, collectionview

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to implement a feature in a collectionView (which is scroll enabled.  By default I want the scroll to be enabled and the pangesturerecgonizer disabled. But after a long press is recognized, the scroll would be disabled and the pan gesture  enabled. After the pan gesture is done, it should be disabled and the scroll should be enabled. I have the following code.

```
lazy var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    let pan =  UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(sender:)))
        pan.delegate = self
    return pan
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    panGesture.isEnabled = false

    let tap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(sender:)))
    tap.delegate = self
    collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    var locationOfBeganTap: CGPoint?

    if sender?.state == .possible { 
    }

    if sender?.state == .ended {
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    }
}

func handleTap(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer? = nil){            
    if sender?.state == .began {
        panGesture.isEnabled = true
        self.collectionView!.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    if sender?.state == .ended {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand, you're saying that when the pan is triggered the scroll can't be disabled and the pan doesn't work anymore?

Try to add also the user interaction for scroll view:

```
collectionV.isScrollEnabled = false
collectionV.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: the collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled is already true.. Perhaps my edit would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply,

`collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`